# Radio button needs to be clicked twice to initiate function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function when a user uses either radio button on a produc page, but this functionality only works when the radio button is clicked twice on first load, then it switches between options with no problem. I have experiementated with various change, click functions and event handlers, but the result is the same.

```js
//toggle subscription dropdown
const changeOptions = function() {
  //When one-time option is selected
  $("input[id='one_time']").on('click', function(e) {
    //update checked status when one-time is selected
    $("#one_time").attr('checked', 'checked');
    $("#subscribe_plan").removeAttr('checked');

    //show/hide logic is option is selected
    if ($(this).attr("checked") === 'checked') {
      formatName();
      $('.js-price').html('<span class="money">' + (selectedVariant.price / 100).toLocaleString(undefined, {
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
        maximumFractionDigits: 2
      }) + '</span>');
      currencyPicker.setCurrencyText();
      Currency.convertAll(shopCurrency, Currency.currentCurrency);

      document.querySelector('.js-selling-plan-id').setAttribute("name", '_');
      document.querySelector('[name="_"]').value = '';
      $('#selling_select').prop("disabled", true);
      $('.subscribe_option').removeClass("d-block");
      $('.subscribe_option').addClass("d-none");
    };
  });
  //When subscription option is selected
  $(document).on('change', "input[id='subscribe_plan']", function(e) {
    //update checked status when subscribe is selected
    $("#subscribe_plan").attr('checked', 'checked');
    $("#one_time").removeAttr('checked');

    //show/hide logic is option is selected
    if ($(this).attr("checked") === 'checked') {
      formatNameSelling();
      const offerPrice = $('.js-price').attr('data-offer-price');
      $('.js-price').html('<span class="money">' + offerPrice + '</span>');
      currencyPicker.setCurrencyText();
      Currency.convertAll(shopCurrency, Currency.currentCurrency);

      const availableSellingPlanAllocations = selectedVariant.selling_plan_allocations;
      const sellingPlan = availableSellingPlanAllocations[0].selling_plan_id;
      document.querySelector('.js-selling-plan-id').setAttribute("name", 'selling_plan');
      document.querySelector('[name="selling_plan"]').value = '';
      $('#selling_select').removeAttr("disabled");
      $('.subscribe_option').removeClass("d-none");
      $('.subscribe_option').addClass("d-block");
    }

    $('select').each(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).find("option[selected]").val());
      // currencyPicker.loadCurrency();
      // currencyPicker.setCurrencyText();
    });
  });
}
//end toggle subscription dropdown

//initiate the function
$(document).ready(function() {
  changeOptions();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--radio 1 -->
<input type="radio" class="" id="one_time" name="option" value="">
<label for="one_time" class="radio_label">
option 1
</label>

<!--radio 2 -->
<input type="radio" class="" id="subscribe_plan" name="option" value="" data-value="" checked="checked">
<label for="subscribe_plan" class="radio_label">
option 2
</label>
```

Comment: weird, this doesn't looks like to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example as recommended on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you trying to make different dropdown menus appear when you select the different options?

Comment: @invizi yes - i am trying to show a hidden div containing a dropdown with options when a user selects the radio input with subscribe_plan

Comment: What is the interest if you don't use a `<form>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that uses only css.

By default the div is hidden, but ehwn you select #one_time, it appears. You can add another one for the other option and it should work. Also alot less effor than all that JS.

```css
.reveal {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.radio #one_time:checked~.reveal {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="one_time" name="option">
    <label for="one_time" class="radio_label">
  option 1
  </label>
    <input type="radio" id="subscribe_plan" name="option" checked="checked">
    <label for="subscribe_plan" class="radio_label">
  option 2
  </label>
    <div class="reveal">
      <input type="text" name="menu" placeholder="Menu">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Invizi - i managed to resolve the issue using JS, based on your css approach. Thanks for the help!